# Having trouble pulling an external api for use in my rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, backend

So for starters, this is the api I am using

https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html

My goal is to pull the information to use for a health app so users can track their food consumption. I am new to this, and am having trouble pulling the data into my backend. this is my seeds.rb file

```
API_HOST = "https://api.nal.usda.gov/"
LIST_PATH = "fdc/v1/foods/list"

  def self.list
    url = "#{API_HOST}#{LIST_PATH}"
    params = {
      dataType: "Branded",
      pageSize: 100,
      sortBy: "asc"
    }

    response = HTTP.auth("Bearer #{ENV['API_KEY']}").get(url, params: params)
    response.parse
  end

  self.list["foods"].each do |food|
    Food.get_foods_list(food)
end
```

In my model for food:

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord


  def  self.get_foods_list(food)
    self.create(
        name: food["description"] ,
        protein: food["foodNutrients"]["nutrientName"]["protein"]["value"],
        carbohydrates:  food["foodNutrients"]["nutrientName"]["carbohydrate, by difference"]["value"],
        fats: food["foodNutrients"]["nutrientName"]["Total lipid (fat)"]["value"]
    )
  end
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant HTTP
```

when I attempt to seed my database with the api data.

I feell like i am missing something small, but I dont know what it is.

This is an example of the data I am trying to pull.

```
foods: [
{
fdcId: 470794,
description: "CHEDDAR CHEESE",
dataType: "Branded",
gtinUpc: "025555300085",
publishedDate: "2019-04-01",
brandOwner: "Coblentz Distributing, Inc.",
ingredients: "PASTEURIZED MILK, CHEESE CULTURE, SALT, ENZYMES AND ANNATTO (VEGETABLE COLOR).",
foodNutrients: [
{
nutrientId: 1005,
nutrientName: "Carbohydrate, by difference",
nutrientNumber: "205",
unitName: "G",
derivationCode: "LCCD",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from a daily value percentage per serving size measure",
value: 0,
},
{
nutrientId: 1079,
nutrientName: "Fiber, total dietary",
nutrientNumber: "291",
unitName: "G",
derivationCode: "LCCD",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from a daily value percentage per serving size measure",
value: 0,
},
{
nutrientId: 1087,
nutrientName: "Calcium, Ca",
nutrientNumber: "301",
unitName: "MG",
derivationCode: "LCCD",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from a daily value percentage per serving size measure",
value: 735,
},
{
nutrientId: 1089,
nutrientName: "Iron, Fe",
nutrientNumber: "303",
unitName: "MG",
derivationCode: "LCCD",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from a daily value percentage per serving size measure",
value: 0,
},
{
nutrientId: 1104,
nutrientName: "Vitamin A, IU",
nutrientNumber: "318",
unitName: "IU",
derivationCode: "LCCD",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from a daily value percentage per serving size measure",
value: 882,
},
{
nutrientId: 1162,
nutrientName: "Vitamin C, total ascorbic acid",
nutrientNumber: "401",
unitName: "MG",
derivationCode: "LCCD",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from a daily value percentage per serving size measure",
value: 0,
},
{
nutrientId: 1003,
nutrientName: "Protein",
nutrientNumber: "203",
unitName: "G",
derivationCode: "LCCS",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from value per serving size measure",
value: 23.53,
},
{
nutrientId: 1004,
nutrientName: "Total lipid (fat)",
nutrientNumber: "204",
unitName: "G",
derivationCode: "LCCS",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from value per serving size measure",
value: 32.35,
},
{
nutrientId: 1008,
nutrientName: "Energy",
nutrientNumber: "208",
unitName: "KCAL",
derivationCode: "LCCS",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from value per serving size measure",
value: 412,
},
{
nutrientId: 2000,
nutrientName: "Sugars, total including NLEA",
nutrientNumber: "269",
unitName: "G",
derivationCode: "LCCS",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from value per serving size measure",
value: 0,
},
{
nutrientId: 1093,
nutrientName: "Sodium, Na",
nutrientNumber: "307",
unitName: "MG",
derivationCode: "LCCS",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from value per serving size measure",
value: 618,
},
{
nutrientId: 1253,
nutrientName: "Cholesterol",
nutrientNumber: "601",
unitName: "MG",
derivationCode: "LCCS",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from value per serving size measure",
value: 103,
},
{
nutrientId: 1257,
nutrientName: "Fatty acids, total trans",
nutrientNumber: "605",
unitName: "G",
derivationCode: "LCCS",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from value per serving size measure",
value: 0,
},
{
nutrientId: 1258,
nutrientName: "Fatty acids, total saturated",
nutrientNumber: "606",
unitName: "G",
derivationCode: "LCCS",
derivationDescription: "Calculated from value per serving size measure",
value: 20.59,
},
],
allHighlightFields: "<b>Ingredients</b>: PASTEURIZED MILK, <em>CHEESE</em> CULTURE, SALT, ENZYMES AND ANNATTO (VEGETABLE COLOR).",
score: 542.84247,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use HTTParty gem for external api calls. Here is the link to the gem https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

This is an idea of what you need

```
class FetchAPI
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "https://api.nal.usda.gov"

  def self.list
    params = {
      dataType: "Branded",
      pageSize: 100,
      sortBy: "asc"
    }

    response = self.class.get("/fdc/v1/foods/list", { headers: "Bearer #{ENV['API_KEY']}"}, query: params)
    response.parse
  end

end

FetchAPI.list["foods"].each do |food|
  Food.get_foods_list(food)
end
```

Comment: this is an updated version of what i have done since posting this question
```
require 'http'

# MY_API = ENV["API_KEY"]
API_HOST = "https://api.nal.usda.gov/"
LIST_PATH = "fdc/v1/foods/list?"

  def list
    url = "#{API_HOST}#{LIST_PATH}api_key=#{ENV['API_KEY']}"
    params = {
      dataType: "Branded",
      pageSize: 100,
      sortOrder: "asc"
    }
  
    response = HTTP.get(url, params: params)
    # byebug
    response.parse
  end
# byebug
  list.each do |food|
    Food.get_foods_list(food)
end
```
 I am getting the data when i check the response in my console

Comment: I am going to try your method though just in case for future reference. I appreciate it. I upvoted your response.